# Returning a map in Firebase cloud function is null

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to return a set of values in a Firebase cloud onCall function, but when I read the value in my Android app, part of the data is missing.

Here is the cloud function:

```
exports.getPhotoUrls = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  let usersAndPhotos = new Map();
  usersAndPhotos.set("bob", "2345");
  usersAndPhotos.set("sam", "345");

  const returnVal = {
    payload: usersAndPhotos,
    status: 200,
    message: "Success"
  }
  console.log("ReturnVal: " );
  console.log(returnVal)

  return returnVal
})
```

When I check in the Firebase functions log, I see that the returned value is:

```
{ payload: Map { 'bob' => '2345', 'sam' => '345' },
  status: 200,
  message: 'Success' }
```

However, when the function returns to my Android app, the payload Map is missing:

[image]

Why is my payload Map data disappearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Map right here:

```
let usersAndPhotos = new Map();
```

is an ES6 Map type object.  It can't be effectively serialized by Cloud Functions callables.  If you want to send a map back to the client, what you should use instead is use a plain old JavaScript object, which has a clear and direct serialization to JSON (which is what's being used as the actual payload):

```
let usersAndPhotos = {
  bob: "2345",
  sam: "345"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  I've done very little Typescript ... how can I do this dynamically?  Something like usersAndPhotos[name] = value?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. This is actually just core JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  I love your Youtube Firebase cloud function series, BTW!  Wish there were more!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Doug's answer, which identified the source of the problem, I was able to make the solution more dynamic with this code:

```
let usersAndPhotos: { Name: string; ID: string; }[] = []
usersAndPhotos.push({Name: "bob", ID: "2345"});
usersAndPhotos.push({Name: "sam", ID: "345"});
```